# Pushing Bluemix app wipes files in the public folder

Tags: node.js, upload, push, ibm-cloud

I have a Bluemix app (with Node.js backend) on which i upload some files (in the folder `public/uploads`).

Whenever I change my server code and `cf push` the app, the files that are in the uploads folder are wiped. How can i publish my app without touching files and folders that I would like not to touch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did one of the solutions below solve your issue?  If so could you please upvote and accept the answer?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the way Cloud Foundry works.  Bluemix runs on Cloud Foundry.  What is causing this is the fact that the file system is ephemeral.  The file system should not be used to store uploaded files.

When an app restarts, crashes, scales, or you upload a new version the file system is wiped.

Additionally if you scale your app to for example 5 instances each instance of your app would have different `uploads`.

I would highly encourage you to check out the [12 Factor App](http://12factor.net/).  One of the tenants is not storing files on disk.

I would encourage you to use a shared file system such as OpenStack Swift.  It is available in Bluemix and is called Object Storage.

Answer (score 2):

Restaging will wipe your files on Cloud Foundry, as there is no permanent local storage available. Try using Bluemix Live Sync to edit your code on the fly -- no restaging required. You can either download the Bluemix Live cli, or use IBM Dev Ops Services to take advantage of Live Edit.  The documentation goes over all the [options](https://www.stage1.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/bluemixlive.html#live_sync-edit).

For more permanent storage solutions, check out the Bluemix catalog for services like Cloudant and Redis.

Answer (score 0):

The file system for cloud foundry applications is ephemeral. Every time your push, restart, scale, you get a new fresh file system. Your application should not store files to disc (except cache/temp). Your application should store the uploaded files in some kind of database or a blob store. Look into the Cloudant service.

[Considerations for Designing and Running an Application in the Cloud](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html)